# jQuery animate decimal number increment/decrement

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I would like to animate difference between two decimal numbers step by step.

Have found [Joss Crowcroft's solution](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/jquery-animate-increment-decrement-numeric-text-elements-value/) for integer numbers that works nice and I've made [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9CuK/).
Code snippet:

```
$({numberValue: 35}).animate({numberValue: 100}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() { 
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    }
});
```

But if I want to animate for example number 2.85 to 3.25, can't be done on ths way. There have to be animated both parts, integer and decimal. Can it be made on simplier way except separated animations for integers and decimals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: 100}, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() { 
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue*100)/100); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: 100}, {
duration: 8000,
easing: 'linear',
step: function (now) {
        $('#dynamic-number').text(now.toFixed(2)); 
}
});
```

Here's [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq13ta4n/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <span id="counter">30</span>
 <span id="counter">25</span>

$("div#counter").each(function( index,element ) {
        var currentNumber = $(element).text();
        $({numberValue: 0}).animate({numberValue: currentNumber}, {
            duration: 1200,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function (now) {
                $(element).text(now.toFixed(0));
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad English, I read all answers and tried this with a larger decimal number, it's not working properly. Why is it not ending on supposed to be exact end number.

```
                    $({ Counter: 1.0000138138}).animate({
                  Counter: 1.0000167238
                }, {
                  duration: 1000,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  step: function() {

                    $('#dynamic-number').html(parseFloat(this.Counter).toFixed(10));
                  }
                });
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/98qncoLr/1/ Just wondering why this fails with larger decimal numbers..