# Increment / decrement numeric jQuery

Tags: jquery

i found this code from [Joss Crowcroft's solution](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/jquery-animate-increment-decrement-numeric-text-elements-value/), maybe similar with this question [jquery-animate-decimal-number-increment-decrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574191/jquery-animate-decimal-number-increment-decrement) the TS have made the example on jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9CuK/)

```
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 110}, {
duration: 1000,
easing:'swing', // can be anything
step: function() { // called on every step
    // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
    $('#el').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "%");
}});
```

but my question is different, when i change the end someValue 110 to big numbers like 1000000 or millions. the end of animate numbers won't be as exact as the end someValue anymore, sometimes it might end up at 999876 or etc below 1000000. How can i make it to end the animated numbers exactly as the endValue?

Comment: Have a callback for the end of the animation and round it up.  Either that or ensure the increment is a multiple of the target.

Comment: could u tell how to make that callback please?

Comment: See the answer posted below talking about a `done()` function - look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a **done** function that will be called when the animation ends, just like **Orbling** suggested:

```
$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: 1000000}, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function () { 
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    },
    done: function () {
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZC4F/

Comment: it works! thank you very much for this, much appreciated (: but how could the result be missed with the big numbers without .done() function ? just curious..

Comment: It is actually being 'missed' too when you use small numbers, but since you're calling **Math.ceil** to round the decimal number upward you're not noticing it. Take a look at this fiddle in which I removed the call to **Math.ceil** and see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/UZQWV/

Comment: yes i noticed it. but doesn't it also mean that when i use big numbers like 1000000 or so, the end of animated numbers didn't reach 99999.xxx so it could be ceiled to 1000000? anyway thanks for the done() function :D

Comment: That depends on the total number of steps. If the number of steps is big enough (longer animation duration), then you would get closer to '99999.xxx'. However, in a short animation you don't get too many steps, hence you could end up getting something like this, considering that between each step your variable is incremented by approximately 300k: 0; 310568; 690198; 924213 (3 steps)